# Математическая операция с BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Имею поля:

```
abstract class Card {
    private long serialNumber;
    private BigDecimal balance;
    private boolean credit;
    private BigDecimal debt;
```

Имею метод:

```
 public void withdraw(BigDecimal request) {
        balance -= request;
    }
```

Выдает ошибку, просит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде все варианты попробовал, все-равно ошибка.
Что ему надо?

Comment: "Выдает ошибку" - ??

Comment: Если это не ошибка, тогда IJ предлагает варианты, но код все-равно подчеркнут красным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю, за что так заминусовали вопрос. Все мы когда-то учились.

Смотрите, составной оператор присваивания:

```
balance -= request;
```

вашем случае раскрывается следующим образом:

```
balance = (BigDecimal) (balance - request);
```

Вся проблема в том, что в Java выполнение операции `balance - request` невозможно. С оператором "минус" могут использоваться только примитивные типы данных, а BigDecimal -- ссылочный тип.

Ваш метод долен выглядеть так:

```
public void withdraw(BigDecimal request) {        
    balance = balance.subtract(request);
}
```

И вообще привыкайте. Там где мы работаем с BigInteger и BigDecimal, операторы +-/*% не применимы. Там всё через методы: add(), substract() и т.п. Так что выражения с BigDecimal получаются очень громоздкими. Но за то вычисления точные.

Comment: Спасибо, что терпимы к "детским" ошибкам.

Comment: Не совсем согласен с "С оператором "минус" могут использоваться только примитивные типы данных".

Comment: И ещё классы **обертки** о них тоже не забываем

Comment: Да, конечно, классы-обёртки. Это, безусловно, синтаксический сахар и под капотом обёртка просто-напросто распаковывается. Но действительно в коде мы их используем с арифметическими операторами напрямую. Это правда.

Answer (score 3):

BigDecimal и BigInteger оба класса имутабельны. Полученный объект изменить нельзя. Операции с объектами производятся только через [методы](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/12.2.php).

```
  MathContext mc = new MathContext(2); // 2 precision

  bg1 = new BigDecimal("100.123");
  bg2 = new BigDecimal("50.56");

  // subtract bg1 with bg2 using mc and assign result to bg3
  bg3 = bg1.subtract(bg2, mc);
```

Comment: Я бы подчеркнул, что **только** через методы, т.к. в Java нет перегрузки операторов.